# Find second derivative of a scalar field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question:

A scalar field $\psi$ depends only on the distance from the origin $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Use the identity $\partial_x r=\frac{x}{r}$ and the chain and product rules to show:

$\begin{align}\partial^2_x \psi=\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)\frac{d\psi}{dr}+\frac{x^2}{r^2}\frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2}\end{align}$

I started with the chain rule:

$\begin{align}\partial_x \psi=\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}&=\frac{d\psi}{dr}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\\ &=\frac{d\psi}{dr}\frac{x}{r}\end{align}$

Then differentiating this as a product:

$\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{d\psi}{dr}\frac{x}{r}\right) \\ &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{d\psi}{dr}\right)\frac{x}{r}+\frac{d\psi}{dr}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)\end{align}$

This is where I get stuck - I'm not sure how to get first term to work out as $\frac{x^2}{r^2}\frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2}$, which is annoying as I'm almost there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an application of the chain rule, you just needed to apply it twice, but you were very close!

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dr}\right)\frac{x}{r}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dr}\right)\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\frac{x}{r}=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial r^2}\frac{x^2}{r^2}$$